# A site to migrate too broad questions from StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, close-reasons

Since there are quite many questions with large number of upvotes being (correctly closed) as "too broad" - should there actually be a site where they could be migrated to.

Part of the problem might be that close votes for questions that are actually more "primarily opinion based" go to "too broad".

Comment: Do you mean like Stack Underflow?

Comment: What good would it do to move them? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: @JoshC Because they are valid questions that people obviously both _want_ and _have_ answers to?

Comment: @Kimvais Due to the fact that it is so broad, it would pretty much become a big discussion then, right?

Comment: Yes - but my whole point sort of is that it could be the _big discussion site_

Comment: @Kimvais Stackexchange is no discussion site.

Comment: @brasofilo, Stack Broadflow ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because the answers to the questions, which are really too broad, would be in best case a blog article. In worst case it would be a complete book with over 1000 pages.

Examples of questions that are too broad:

- how to implement (audio/video) format in Java?
- how to proof PHP application against (technique)?
- how to learn Oracle administration if I already know Turbo Pascal?

The problem with the questions that are too broad is, that either they can be splitted into a few dozen of elementary questions, or the OP needs to read a book or a set of resources in order to get enough knowledge to accomplish its task.